# Is it possible to generate Javadoc pages for each level of a package?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, documentation, javadoc, package-info

I have a package in Java called `foo.abc.xyz` (name changed). The `xyz` level of the package has no source files, but it contains subpackages such as `asdf` and `qwerty` that do contain classes. I have a `package-info.java` file with a comment for that level of the package, but when I generate the Javadoc, pages are generated for `foo.abc.xyz.asdf` and `foo.abc.xyz.qwerty`, but not for just `foo.abc.xyz`. Its `package-info.java` file seems to be entirely ignored. Is there a way to make Javadoc generate separate pages for every level of a package, not just ones that contain classes? I'm using the Javadoc generator in Intellij IDEA, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Note: packages do not have "levels" ... as far as the Java language or the Java tool chains are concerned.  As far as the JLS is concerned, a package with no classes in it does not exist.